# Get current path with äöüè in name (__FILE__)

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, directory

Using Windows, I've experienced a slight annoyance when using `__FILE__` to get the current location of a file or the absolute path of another file with

```
File.expand_path("lib/other", File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

This doesn't work though if the folder has characters like `äöüè` and similar. This get's especially annoying if the windows username of a client contains such a character and my script necessarily lives inside the `%appdata%` folder.

To demonstrate my problem, `C:\äüé\test.rb` contains only

```
puts __FILE__
```

Running it:

```
> ruby C:\äüé\test.rb
C:/"?'/test.rb
```

Is there a reliable way to get the current file path?

Comment: ruby version? Support for unicode has gotten better over the years.

Comment: Locally I'm running the latest `2.2.3p173`, but I'm required to target `2.0.0` in production. This problem occurs in both versions.

Comment: http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=180&t=57017